# How to upload and download pdf files in flutter app using firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, dart

I am making a flutter app in which I need to upload pdf files to firebase storage and then downloading and opening those pdf files from firebase storage to the android device. I dont know how to do this and there is no documentation on the flutter website for this also. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has multiple parts:

**For pdf viewing:**

search in pub.dev for pdf and you'll find multiple packages.

**For uploading using Firebase:**

You can use the `file_picker` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to allow the user to pick files. Then use firebase storage to upload that file.

```
StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path); 

StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(pickedFile);

StorageTaskSnapshot ref = await uploadTask.onComplete;

// to get the download URL and save it somewhere

String url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
```

Store the downloadUrl to use it later or you can get the downloadURL again using the same approach (i.e. `reference.getDownloadURL()`)

**For downloading:**

You can either use the downloadURL directly to get the file and pass it to the pdf viewer, or use FirebaseStroage method `reference.getData(maxSize)` but note you've to specify the maxSize. Then pass the data to the pdf viewer of your choice. Maybe you can find a viewer that will show data directly from URL and that'll make it easier.